# Jenkins : add a calendar or date input as a parameter to freestyle project

Tags: jenkins

I am working on a FreeStyle project in Jenkins and I would like to ask the user for date as a parameter. I can manually create that, by just adding months, day, year numbers, but it won't be accurate. Is there anyway to create a date-time parameter which is accurate in Jenkins?

This is my problem :

[image]

As you can see this is wrong. But I am not able to add any logic to these parameters.

Comment: Are you thinking about something like this: https://plugins.jenkins.io/date-parameter/?

Comment: I expect what is desired is similar to unreleased [date-picker-plugin](https://github.com/rajvimalc/date-picker-plugin). A request to release or a [JIRA improvement](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/projects/JENKINS/issues/) to the [date-parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/date-parameter) is suggested. Or you  could roll your own using [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) or [Extended Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter/)

Comment: @IanW : Yes, the date-picker is something I am looking for, although installation for it is failing.

Comment: Suggest you reach out to the the developer as he has not formally released it (locally or in plugins.jenkins.io and not listed any build instructions to build yourself.